# Is there a ttl option for rabbitmq exchanges?

Tags: rabbitmq

TTL can be set on queues, so they will expire after a period of time if they are not used. Is there a similar option for exchanges?

I'm trying to build a social application and each exchange represents a user. Each time someone wants to send a message to this user, he would send the message to the user exchange. If number of the users become large, like 20 million users, there would be 20 million exchanges in the system. I'm afraid that much exchanges degrade the system. Instead I want to only keep exchanges for online users.
By the way the messages are only valuable if the user is online and I don't want to store messages for later delivery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a separate exchange for every user ideed would be overkill. Try a different approach.

- Use a *single* `direct` exchange.
- When a client comes online it creates a new exclusive, auto-delete queue and consumes from it.
- The client also binds the single exchange to its queue using the name of the user as the routing key.
- Producers publish messages to the single exhange with the name of the user as the routing key of the message.

This will automatically

- only keep queues for online users and
- discard messages for offline users.

**Edit:** If a user shall be able to use multiple clients, that's possible using the above approach.

- Every client creates a new exclusi auto-delete queue and consumes from it *as above*.
- It binds the single exchange to this queue *as above*.

Note that it is possible to have multiple bindings from an exchange using identical routing keys. Every client has its own queue and its own binding, even if the routing key on this binding is the same routing key as on another binding created by a different client.

Comment: thanks. Your suggestion is indeed valid with this scenario, but there is some extra info about our design. Each user can access the app from different clients. For example from a mobile device and a PC, so each device need a separate queue, so user can receive messages at the same time on both  clients.

Comment: By the way, is there a solution for specifying ttl on exchanges?